# iPhone Ad Hoc Distribution Build does not work on 3.x Devices

Tags: iphone, ios4, entitlements

We have made many Distribution Builds, so we are familiar with the daunting iPhone provisioning process.

We have entered all the devices into the Provision Portal, we have downloaded all certificates, and when we distribute our BETA build, it is only working for users on iOS 4.x.  This is strange behavior because it wasn't doing this before.

**Our iOS Deployment Target is set to: iOS 3.0**

**Base SDK is: iOS Device 4.1**

Don't you think if we had a reference to a Base 4 SDK method, that it would at least install, but then crash?  We are getting the infamous:

"The executable was signed with invalid entitlements"

This seems like an odd error when other all other devices that are on iOS 4 are working and all the iOS 3 devices are getting this?

We are stumped, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing a build and archive? You might want to try building it and manually zipping it along with the provision and sending that to your beta testers. I had this same problem with iOS 3 devices and zipping it manually seemed to work.

Comment: I was doing a build, then grabbing it out of the build folder and zipping it with the .mobileprovision file.  I hadn't had problems up until 3.x.  Should I not include the .mobileprovision file in the zip?  I never used Build and Archive, while you had problems with it, maybe it is my solution, as I have seen funny behaviors from Xcode.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Versions of iOS prior to 3.2 cannot take advantage of an embedded provision file (included in the zip). For those devices, you have to install the .mobileprovision file separately by dragging it into the library in iTunes.

Comment: Josh, thanks for the insight, did not now that.  I did drag them over manually and watched the person do it, I also confirmed by looking on their iPhone under setting to confirm it was there.

Comment: I am going to try creating an .ipa file from this guide, see if that helps.  Also, note that both devices were being installed on macs, not windows.

Comment: That guide was written before "Build and Archive" was added as an option to Xcode. "Build and Archive" is what I use, and it seems to work painlessly.